# Cylindrical Carousel like shinobi carousel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, carousel

I want to implement carousel like [ShinobiCarousel](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2014/02/11/building-a-paged-carousel) Cylindrical

Is there any other alternative for Carousel's in iOS.
I have seen iCarousel by nicklockwood. but the effect I want to use is available only in shinobi. I want same as screenshot attached [image]

Could someone help me to achieve the same effect in iCarousel ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the type of carousal you looking for is present in the iCarousel by nicklockwood . Not sure which one  but have you tried :

1. iCarouselTypeCoverFlow
2. iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2

this will gives you rough appearance of the look and feel you wanted . But for getting the exact one , you have to play with the radius , numberOfVisibleItems ,angle etc

Comment: Yes I have seen that and tried to play with radius,spacing and other factors but not able to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot predict what is happening :( . But once in a past I had same problem where I had to make customise carousel with cylindrical effect . After been playing for long time I achieved that, . Thats why I suggested to you ! Otherwise you have to look for some other libraries :) .

Comment: sorry ,It was two years ago . But I do remember that I played with radius,spacing and other factors for a long time to achieve the desired results .